# Localisation on Chinese traditional [zh-TW] fails on internet explorer windows 8.1

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, localization, windows-8.1

Localisation is set to **Chinese traditional [zh-TW]** in internet explorer. During navigation on site the `Accept language` tag in internet explorer shows

> zh-Hant-TW,zh-Hant;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

The server tries to convert the langage using `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture` but it fails and convert to wrong Cultureinfo `zh-CN`, and localisation fail

Comment: Please show what argument you are passing to `CreateSpecificCulture` . According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.createspecificculture(v=vs.110).aspx the Culture name is `zh-Hant` but the _Specific_ Culture name is `zh-HK`.

Comment: The argument from the function is fetched from the `UserLanguages` properties from the `request` object. in this case the argument is `zh-Hant-TW`

Comment: Well, try a simple `if(lang=="zh-Hant-TW) lang="zh-HK";` before calling `CreateSpecificCulture` in order to catch that specific case.